# How do I enable remote access/request to Elastic APM-server?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, apm, elastic-apm

I have setup of Elastic with APM server on single machine. I've configured APM java agent to push traces to APM server on localhost. Everything works fine with localhost configuration on Windows.

Now, I'm looking to run apm java agent for application running on different machine on the same network. That is apm java agent on linux & apm server running on windows machine.

Default APM-server listen to localhost. I tried to change setting on apm-server.yml file with -

```
apm-server:
  # Defines the host and port the server is listening on.  use "unix:/path/to.sock" to listen on a unix domain socket.
  host: "hot-ip:8200"
```

default is:

```
host:"localhost:8200".
```

After making apm-server.yml change, process explorer show apm-server.exe process listening to IP- host-ip port- 8200 protocol- TCP. 
But, still http://host-ip:8200 is not accessible from other machine on network. While on the same machine (windows) http://localhost:8200 & http://host-ip:8200 works fine & give below response.

```
{
build_date: "2019-05-23T12:58:36Z",
build_sha: "410bf33fa1b67fa5bd02a388de17d0e30ec031da",
version: "7.1.1",
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

To listen on `0.0.0.0` try:

```
  host: ":8200"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is a firewall blocking the traffic (like Window's built-in one)?
2. `10.9.21.91` is the IP that hosts are trying to reach? Just to be sure you could bind to `host: "0.0.0.0:8200"`, which would cover all possible interfaces.

Comment: i think this should be in comment section than in answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "localhost:8200" with "0.0.0.0:8200" in apm-server.yml